# Ibid not used in floating mdframed

Tags: biblatex, floats, mdframed

I have some boxes that I would like to treat as floating environments. I have a custom environment for the floats in my original document, but the problem I'm encountering reproduces with `figure`.

When a citation occurs consecutively in an mdframed float, the citations appear at the bottom of the box (as desired), but do not use ibid, unlike elsewhere. How can I ensure ibid is used in such circumstances?

MWE. My intended output is like the second box but floating like the first.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[b6paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Labov1972,
    Address = {Philadelphia},
    Author = {William Labov},
    Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
    Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
    Year = {1972}}

@book{Chomsky1957,
    Address = {The Hague},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {Mouton},
    Title = {Syntactic Structures},
    Year = {1957}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

La\footcite{Labov1972} and La\footcite{Labov1972}

\begin{mdframed}
La\footcite{Chomsky1957} and La\footcite{Chomsky1957}
\end{mdframed}

\begin{figure}
\begin{mdframed}
La\footcite{Labov1972} and La\footcite{Labov1972}
\end{mdframed}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating structures are a bit tricky with respect to citation tracking as they are in a way outside the text flow. So `biblatex` disables citation tracking there by default.

See also §4.11.5 *Trackers in Floats and TOC/LOT/LOF*

> If a citation is given in a float (typically in the caption of a figure or table), scholarly back references like ‘ibidem’ or back references based on the page tracker get ambiguous because floats are objects which are (physically and logically) placed outside the flow of text, hence the logic of such references applies poorly to them. To avoid any such ambiguities, the citation and page trackers are temporarily disabled in all floats.

in the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

We can re-enable it with

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \apptocmd\@floatboxreset
    {\booltrue{citetracker}%
     \booltrue{pagetracker}}
    {}
    {\blx@err@patch{floats}}
}
\makeatother
```

This gives the expected output in most cases, but if your boxes float 'too much' you might see unexpected results.

In the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[b6paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Labov1972,
    Address = {Philadelphia},
    Author = {William Labov},
    Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
    Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
    Year = {1972}}

@book{Chomsky1957,
    Address = {The Hague},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {Mouton},
    Title = {Syntactic Structures},
    Year = {1957}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \apptocmd\@floatboxreset
    {\booltrue{citetracker}%
     \booltrue{pagetracker}}
    {}
    {\blx@err@patch{floats}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

La\footcite{Labov1972} and La\footcite{Labov1972}

\begin{mdframed}
La\footcite{Chomsky1957} and La\footcite{Chomsky1957}
\end{mdframed}

\begin{figure}
\begin{mdframed}
La\footcite{Labov1972} and La\footcite{Labov1972}
\end{mdframed}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

it does the right thing.

[image: example output]